# within function warnings when using while in a function

Tags: r

I write a function to calculate critical depth of water in a circular channel
while the flow (Q) and diameter (d) are given:

```
D_Critic<- function (Q,Dia) {

    g=9.81 
    Diff=1      
    Phi=0.01
    while(Diff>=0.001)   {
      A=16*Q*sqrt((2/g)*sin(Phi/2))
      B=Dia^5/2*(Phi-sin(Phi))^3/2
      Diff=A-B
      Phi=Phi+0.001
      Yc=Dia/2*(1-cos(Phi/2))
    }

return(Yc)
}
```

now I want to use within function to bind Yc with dataframe DQ, but it returns only first calculated Yc and several repeated warnings:

```
Q<-c(2.5975,2.5900,2.4183,2.3077)
D<-c(1,1,1,1)
DQ<-data.frame(Q,D) 
> D_Q<-within(DQ,Yc<-D_Critic( Q/2, D))
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> D_Q
       Q D   Yc
1 2.5975 1 0.52609
2 2.5900 1 0.52609
3 2.4183 1 0.52609
4 2.3077 1 0.52609

> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In while (Diff >= 0.001) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` statement only takes one boolean value, e.g. `Diff >= 0.001` where `Diff` must be a single number. In the first time you go through the loop, this is the case, as `Diff` equals 1. However, in the second instance, `Diff` becomes equal to `A-B`, where `A` and `B` are both vectors of length 4.

So, when your code reaches the second iteration, `while` generates a warning, as it is not sure how to deal with a vector of booleans. The choice it makes is to simply use the first element in the boolean vector, discarding the rest.

You need to consider what `Diff` actually is. Probably a single number, so `Diff sum(A-B)` or `sum((A-B)^2)`. This would result in a single `Diff` value, and get rid of your errors. What `Diff` should exactly depends on the theory you are working on. Your text book should list this.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved with a trick:

```
Yc<-matrix(NA,length(DQ$Q),1)
for (i in 1:length(DQ$Q)) {

  Yc[i,1]<- D_Critic(DQ$Q[i]/2,DQ$D[i])
}
> Yc
          [,1]
[1,] 0.5260900
[2,] 0.5255907
[3,] 0.5163489
[4,] 0.5098512
DQ<-cbind(DQ,Yc)
> DQ
       Q D        Yc
1 2.5975 1 0.5260900
2 2.5900 1 0.5255907
3 2.4183 1 0.5163489
4 2.3077 1 0.5098512
```